# MVC grouping checkbox fields in form from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have data in model from which checkboxes are created. Functionality wise, it's similar to a survey.

I have free text, drop down and radio button working fine, but checkboxes are a big problem. I want the question answered, thus the field has to be `required` and checkboxes are "grouped" only if the name is the same, however given the fact that I'm using razor to format the checkboxes, regardless of using `CheckBoxFor()` method or manually writing `<input asp-for="...` checkboxes are still not group because ASP Generates the name field which in the ends turns out to be `Questions[0].Options[0,1,2,3,...].IsChecked`

Without the required attribute everything works fine, but that way people can leave questions unanswered.

```
@for (var j = 0; j < Model.Questions[i].Options.Count(); j++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-control">
            @Html.HiddenFor(chk => chk.Questions[i].Options[j].OptionId)

            //CheckboxForMethod
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(chk => chk.Questions[i].Options[j].Checked, new { @required = "required" })

            //Manual method - Name field gets overwritten
            <input asp-for="@Model.Questions[i].Options[j].Checked" name="@Model.Questions[i].Title" required="required" type="checkbox">

            @Html.DisplayFor(chk => chk.Questions[i].Options[j].Title)
          </div>
    </div>
}
```

Obviously in this kind of situation I can't use a generic property of the question model because 1 bool property can't monitor N options, but going deeper leaves the issue of the html's name attribute..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I render a group of checkboxes using MVC 4 and View Models (strongly typed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808936/how-do-i-render-a-group-of-checkboxes-using-mvc-4-and-view-models-strongly-type)

Comment: @derloopkat Wouldn't work. I already tried this method, and it's even mentioned in the code.

Comment: In your CheckBoxFor add attribute @Name = "group". Note that "Name" starts with capital.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by _grouping checkbox fields_. A `CheckBoxFor()` method is for binding to a `bool` and posts back either `true` or `false`, both of which are valid for `bool` (a `[Required]` attribute means the value cannot be `null`)

Comment: You're not getting the point. A group of checkboxes with SAME Name in HTML means that one (or all) can have attribute "Required" attached to them, which warns you if NONE of the checkboxes are checked and that at least one should be checked. With having different Name attribute, the checkboxes are not a part of the same HTML-FORM-wise group and with required tag ALL have to be checked to allow the browser to post it back.

Comment: @derloopkat It makes no difference, doesn't work regardless of capitalization.

Comment: @StephenMuecke here's the problem: if none are checked, it gives expected error: http://prnt.sc/ceir41
but since checkboxes aren't grouped together, this happens next, which shouldn't.: http://prnt.sc/ceirb2

Comment: @DethoRhyne, The images you have shown are not behavior that is part of default MVC and your obviously using some jquery plugins which you have not told us about and/or your disabling client side validation. Second, your not changing the `name` attribute (fortunately, or else nothing would bind to you model). Third, you cannot _group_ checkboxes (you can however group radio buttons).

Comment: Forth, as I noted above, a [Required]` attribute means the value will be invalid if its `null` and the `CheckBoxFor()` method posts back either `True` or `False` and it will NEVER be `null` (unless a malicious user is hacking your app)

Comment: You have a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you need to explain what it is that you trying to achieve. Do you want one and one only checkbox to be checked, or at least one (could be many) checkbox to be checked?

Comment: I'm not using jquery plugins besides jquery, and no javascript is even used here. the warning messages are default by browser, but, you were correct about the XY I guess. I do remember that we did something similar years quite some time ago in uni and that the checkboxes were grouped, so I assumed it's the same thing as a radiobutton... Looks like I'll actually have to get a jquery plugin to take care of this.. Thanks for opening my eyes though!